# Django using a global Template and Views

Tags: python, django, django-views

so im new to Python and Django, im wondering if there is a concept like a template for the whole app/site like

```
<html>
...
<body>
{% content_goes_here %}
</body>
```

and than you got your views:

```
<tr>
{% name %}
</tr>
..
```

so i can use views as building blocks for my site but have a global template that does all the css/head/script/html stuff.

I know this concept from cakephp for example. How is this done in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using [template inheretance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)